# How do you typeset code elements in normal text?

Tags: language-agnostic, format

What is the best way to typeset a function with arguments for readibility, brevity, and accuracy? I tend to put empty parentheses after the function name like `func()`, even if there are actually arguments for the function.  I have trouble including the arguments and still feeling like the paragraph is readable.

Any thoughts on best practices for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually take that approach, but if I feel like it's going to cause confusion, I'll use ellipses like: `myFunction(...)`

I guess if I were good, I would use those *any* time I was omitting parameters from a function in text.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply be a little more careful with the name of my variables and parameters, most people will then be able to guess much more accurately what type of data you want to hold in it.